# Opportunity StageName metadata retrieve in API 39

Tags: metadata, migration-tool

I was trying to migrate some standard fields like Account Type, Opportunity Type and Opportunity StageName with Migration Tool with API version 39.0 but am i don't see any pick list values in Metadata (Now named as ValueSet) for only Standard pick list fields.

Even i cross checked in IDE for the object,i dont see any values for those pick lists, is it known issue from Salesforce?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is a dedicated metadata for such standard picklist field [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm) mappings between field names and standardvalueset names can be explored [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)

so to retrieve/deploy `Opportunity.StageName` field you need to have the following lines in your `package.xml`

```
<types>
    <members>OpportunityStage</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```